# How to get Constructor Generic parameter type using reflection c#

Tags: c#

Hi All Thanks in advance.
I have a class and a parameterize constructor and i want to read Constructor parameters type. Let say

```
Class A
{    
    public A(Helper help)
    {
       // code
    }
}
```

In the above code we can read constructor using below code
Code:

```
Type ClassType = typeof(A);
ConstructorInfo[] Constructors = ClassType.GetConstructors();
foreach (ConstructorInfo constInfo in Constructors)
{
    if (constInfo.GetParameters().Count() > 0)
    {
        RefNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (ParameterInfo parameters in constInfo.GetParameters())
        {
             Type newType = parameters.ParameterType;
        }
    }
}
```

So in newType i will get Type of "Helper" class but i want type from generic interface.
e.g

```
Class A
{    
    public A(IHelper<Helper> help)
    {
       // code
    }
}
```

// where Helper class inheriting from IHelper interface
Now i want type of IHerper interface i.e Type of Helper
How can i get it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not going to ask you why you are doing it but you can get the generic type used by accessing `GenericTypeArguments` property of `ParameterInfo`:

```
Type newType = parameters.ParameterType.GenericTypeArguments.First();
```

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: @MdIstiyaQ No problems, glad to hear it has solved your problem. Mark this as answer if you don't mind then.